Prisma Nextjs Getting undefined session before getting to submitData on form
I am making an edit function for objects in my postgres database. I am using nextauth as well for my session. When I try to submit form data (like updating the fields defined in my schema), I get an error, client_fetch_error undefined Posting to the database works just fine. (By the way I am new to web development as a whole)
I am using next version 12.1.2 and next-auth 4.24.6
Apologies if I didn't include some information that would be useful, ask away if I left out anything.
Here is the route that has all of the code for the edit page,
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import Layout from "../../../components/Layout";
import Router from "next/router";
import { PostProps } from "../../../components/Post";
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const course = await prisma.course.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: String(params?.id) ,
    },
    include: {
      author: {
        select: { name: true, email: true,},
      },
    },
  });
  return {
    props: course,
  };
};

const Post: React.FC<PostProps> = (props) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <div>Authenticating ...</div>;
  }
  const userHasValidSession = Boolean(session);
  const postBelongsToUser = session?.user?.email === props.author?.email;
  let title = props.title;
  
  title = `${title}`;
  
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [number, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [courseid, setCourseid] = useState("");

  const submitData = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    console.log("got to submit")
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const body = { title, courseid, name, email, number, desc };
      await fetch(`/api/post/${props.id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      await Router.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>By {props?.author?.name || "Unknown author"}</p>
        <ReactMarkdown children={props.desc} />
        <form onSubmit={submitData}>
          
          <h3>Course ID</h3>
          <input
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setCourseid(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="e.g. Math 301"
            type="text"
            value={courseid}
          />
          
          <h3>Teacher's Name</h3>
          <input
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Teacher Name"
            type="text"
            value={name}
          />
          <h3>Email</h3>
          <input
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
            value={email}
          />
          <h3>Phone</h3>
          <input
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Number"
            type="text"
            value={number}
          />
       
          <textarea
            cols={50}
            onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Important Notes"
            rows={8}
            value={desc}
          />
           {userHasValidSession && postBelongsToUser && (
          <button type="submit">Edit</button>
        )}
          <a className="back" href="#" onClick={() => Router.push("/")}>
            or Cancel
          </a>
          
        </form>

      </div>
      
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Post;


Here is my api page that handles the edit and delete [id].ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'

export default async function handle(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const postId = req.query.id;
  const { title, courseid, desc, name, email, number } = req.body;
  const session = await getSession({ req })

  if (req.method === "DELETE") {
    if (session) {
      const post = await prisma.course.delete({
        where: { id: String(postId) },
      });
      res.json(post);
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' })
    }
  } 
  else if (req.method === "PUT") {
    console.log("got to api")
    console.log(postId)
    if (session) {
      console.log("got thru if statement in api")
      const post = await prisma.course.update({
        where: { id: String(postId) },
        data: {
          title: title,
          courseid: courseid,
          desc: desc,
        },
      });
      res.json(post);
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'Unauthorized' })
    }
  }
  else {
    throw new Error(
      `The HTTP ${req.method} method is not supported at this route.`
    );
  }
}


This is what's being logged to the console:
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
got to api
clv5u15cn0000udk0yd2rt9i1


Can you share what it says in the network tab in the chrome devtools? Also, did you try logging the id that you're using in the api url string? If you're expecting that id to come from the props: course you're returning from the getServerSideProps I think it will actually be nested, so maybe props.props.id, but you should definitely check before calling the route anyways.

FYI I just included the api route code in my original post. The network tab responds with {"message":"Unauthorized"} with the name being the id of the post.  It's definitely getting the id of the post and all, it even makes it to the api call but I believe it halts when it gets to the if(session) in [id].ts. (in other words, the console.log("got to api") runs but the console.log("got thru if statement in api") does not. )

I think your issue isn't in the API route then, but rather in where you're actually authorizing the user. Do you have this in a repo I can take a look at real quick?

Turns out it was the pesky getSession function. I just had to change to getServerSession and it worked.
